# Typescript union type inference

Tags: typescript

How would I achieve type inference in the following case:

```
type a = {
    foo: number;
    bar: string;
}

type b = {
    foo: string;
}

let baz: a | b;

if (baz.foo === 5) {
    baz.bar = "abc"; // baz type is still a | b, should be a
}
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20a%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20b%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20baz%3A%20a%20%7C%20b%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(baz.foo%20%3D%3D%3D%205)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baz.z%20%3D%20%22123%22%3B%0D%0A%7D

Comment: "If we have a value that has a union type, we can only access members that are common to all types in the union." https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently types cannot be inferred from the types of their properties, so you will need to define a type guard:

```
type a = {
    foo: number;
    bar: string;
}

type b = {
    foo: string;
}

let baz: a | b;

function isA(x: a | b): x is a {
    return typeof x.foo === 'number';
}

if (isA(baz) && baz.foo === 5) {
    baz.bar = "123";
}
```

The `isA` type guard will tell TypeScript that you have checked `baz`s type yourself. Below is another way to achieve this with casts, but here you still need to cast `baz` for every usage which is probably not the best way to do this.

```
if ((baz as a).foo === 5) {
    (baz as a).z = "123";
}
```

More information about type guards can be found in [the TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

Answer (score 0):

> baz type is still a | b, should be a

Actually what the TypeScript compiler does is restricts property access of all unified types (`a | b`) to properties that exist on all of them, thus, `baz.bar` does not even compile because `bar` does not exist on type `b`.